# Bootstrap Table show entries Don't show exact number of Cells

Tags: javascript, php, html

with my small knowledge coding PHP I struggled about 4 days to make DataTable show exact entries what customer chose. Below is my code for getting data from Mysql DataBase

```
<?php 
include("check.php"); 
include("config.php");

// Create connection
//$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = 'SELECT * from transaction';
if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
}

$count=0;
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

?>
```

And here is my html for displaying Table which one must have pagination and customer could choose how much cells he want to see (ex: 10, 25, 50, 100)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>მთავარი გვერდი</title>

        <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- Bootstrap core CSS-->

        <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->

        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- Page level plugin CSS-->

        <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body class="fixed-nav sticky-footer bg-dark" id="page-top">
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <?php include("template/navigbar.php"); ?>

        <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
        <?php include("template/breadc.php"); ?>
        <!-- Icon Cards-->

        <!-- Example DataTables Card-->

        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                <i class="fa fa-table"></i> Data Table Example</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="myTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>თქვენი ID</th>
                        <th>თარიღი</th>
                        <th>ობიექტი</th>
                        <th>ტერმინალი</th> 
                        <th>თანხა</th> 
                        <th>ჯამი</th> 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        $count =$count + $row['amount']; 
                        echo '
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                <td>'.$row["trID"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['userID'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['trDate'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['obName'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['terName'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['amount'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$count.'</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            ';
                    }
                    ?>   
                </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

But the result is always full Table with Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries but in the table it shows me more then 25 cell.[See Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEIBM.png)

Please let me know what I m doing wrong?

Comment: Using `view-source:` is a good way to check the HTML generated by your PHP code and you can check if there's anything wrong there.

Comment: `<tbody>` must be outside of loop.

Comment: @AjayMakwana Man I think I'm doing very stupid  faults. Thank you you saved my next 1 day maybe 2 :) you are great

Comment: @AleksAndersonITSo Can I post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this as an answer because it solves the issue.

`<tbody>` must be outside of loop

Answer (score 0):

Put your `tbody` tags outside of `while` statement.

Comment: Please provide some explanations with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the tbody BEFORE start the loop.

In your code, you are creating a new tbody for each row instead just a row.

Dont forget to close the tbody after the php close tag

tbody must be out site of the loop

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this code will help you

```
'aLengthMenu': [[50, 100, 150, -1], [50, 100, 150, "All"]],
  'iDisplayLength': '50'
```